# Tutorial for Tree Data Structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Could someone direct me to some tutorial on Tree Data Structures using C. I tried googling but most implementations are for C++ or Java.If someone can point me to some online tutorials that are in C it would be great.

Thanks..

Comment: Read Any Good DATA STRUCTURE book.

Comment: Look under section 4 at https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece250/Lectures/Slides/ The site has many other data structures and algorithm implementations and explanation about them and their run time/ asymptotic analysis

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generic tree-traversal methods: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal (see right sidebar for a huge list of algorithms to choose from).

Some tutorials:

- http://randu.org/tutorials/c/ads.php
- http://www.ehow.com/how_2056293_create-binary-tree-c.html

Comment: Thanks eruciform ...Just what i was looking for.

Comment: no problem - please click the green checkmark when you get a chance

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of tutorial code from a couple of decades ago. In fact, it's been lying around so long, I don't remember where it came from or who wrote it (could have been me, but I'm really not sure). Theoretically it's a bit non-portable, using `strdup`, which isn't part of the standard library, though most compilers have/supply it.

```
/* Warning: untested code with no error checking included. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* A tree node. Holds pointers to left and right sub-trees, and some data (a string).
 */
typedef struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char *string;
} node;

node *root; /* pointers automatically initialized to NULL */

int insert(const char *string, node *root) {

    /* Add a string to the tree. Keeps in order, ignores dupes.
     */
    int num = strcmp(root->string, string);
    node *temp;

    for(;;) {
        if ( 0 == num)
            /* duplicate string - ignore it. */
            return 1;
        else if (-1 == num) {
            /* create new node, insert as right sub-tree.
             */
            if ( NULL == root -> right ) {
                temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
                temp -> left = NULL;
                temp -> right = NULL;
                temp -> string = strdup(string);
                return 2;
            }
            else
                root = root -> right;
        }
        else if ( NULL == root ->left ) {
            /* create new node, insert as left sub-tree.
             */
            temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp -> left = NULL;
            temp -> right = NULL;
            temp -> string = strdup(string);
            return 2;
        }
        else
            root = root -> left;
    }
}


void print(node *root) {   
    /* in-order traversal -- first process left sub-tree.
     */
    if ( root -> left != NULL )
        print(root->left);
    /* then process current node.
     */
    fputs(root->string, stdout);

    /* then process right sub-tree
     */
    if ( root->right != NULL )
        print(root->right);
}

int main() {

    char line[100];

    /* Let user enter some data. Enter an EOF (e.g., ctrl-D or F6) when done.
     */
    while ( fgets(line, 100, stdin))
        insert(line, root);

    /* print out the data, in order
     */
    print(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jerry..I was looking more for some tutorial rather than the actual code. I wanted to get a good grip on the concepts and then try it out myself...Anyways thanks!!!

Comment: @The Stig: Ah, but this is purely a starting point -- it doesn't currently support looking up particular values (should be pretty easy), deletion (somewhat non-trivial), maintaining balance (*decidedly* non-trivial), etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct binary_node {
        struct binary_node *left;
        struct binary_node *right; int value;
};

typedef struct binary_node NODE;

int search(NODE *temp, int data)
{
        int found = 0;

#if 0
        while (temp == NULL) {
                if (temp->value == data) {
                        found = 1;
                        break;
                }
                else if (temp->value > data)
                        temp = temp->left;
                else if (temp->value < data)
                        temp = temp->right;
        }
        return found;
#endif

        if (temp == NULL)
                return 0;
        else if (temp->value == value)
                return 1;
        else if (temp->value > data)
                return search(temp->left, data);
        else if (temp->value < data)
  }




NODE *del(NODE *root, int val)
{
        if (root = NULL)
                return ;
        if (val < root->val)
                root->left = delete(root->left, val);
        else if (val > root->val)
                root->right = delete(root->right, val);

        else {
                if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
                        temp = root;
                        free(temp);
                        root = NULL;
                }
                else if (root->left == NULL) {
                        temp = root;
                        root = root->right;
                        free(temp);
                }
                else if (root->right == NULL) {
                        temp = root;
                        root = root->left;
                        free(temp);
                }
                else {
                        temp = min(root->right);
                        root->data = temp->data;
                        root->right = delete(root->right, temp->data);
                }
        }

                return root;
}



NODE *insert_node(NODE *node, int val)
{

        if (*node == NULL) {
                node = (NODE *) malloc (sizeof(NODE));
                node->left = NULL;
                node->right = NULL;
                node->value = val;
        }

        if (node->value > val)
                node->left = insert_node(node->left, val);
        else if (node->value < val)
                node->right = insert_node(node->right, val);
        else
                printf("Discarding the data as it already exists in node\n");

        return node;
}

}
int main()
{

        NODE *root = NULL;

        root = insert_node(root, 50);
        insert_node(root, 4);
        insert_node(root, 14);
        insert_node(root, 44);
        insert_node(root, 24);
        insert_node(root, 34);
        insert_node(root, 74);
        insert_node(root, 54);
        insert_node(root, 64);

        print_order(&root);

        search(&root, 34);
        del(&root);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely very useful or well received, but in this case the (ancient) question isn't asking for code at all, but rather for a reference to external documentation (a tutorial), so the code is barely responsive to the question at all.  By the way, the question does not meet SO's current standards.  If it were posed today, it would be quickly closed.